# How do I get the text value of a node if it sometimes has another inner element?

Tags: xpath

Sometimes the node returns without the a node and sometimes it does.

```
//div[@class="title"]/a/text()
//div[@class="title"]/text()

<div class"title>
  <a>Book 1</a>
</div>
<div class"title>
  Book 1
</div>
```

Comment: what about `//div[@class="title"]//text()`?

Comment: Ah thanks! I didn't know why that didn't cross my mind.